# What is causing this Android Studio Error Message: Cannot Resolve Method

Tags: java, android-studio

Java is not my first language, so there is probably a very simple answer. I am in Android Studio.

I have a Java file Security.java with class:

```
public class Security {
   ...
   public static boolean verifyPurchase(String base64PublicKey, String signedData,
                                      String signature) throws IOException {
   {
       boolean bl;
       ...
       return bl;
   }
}
```

This file has no red error issues.

Then in another Java file I have another function:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PurchasesUpdatedListener {
   private static final String licenceKey = "mykey";

   ...

   private boolean verifyValidSignature(String signedData, String signature) {
        try {
            // To get key go to Developer Console > Select your app > Development Tools > Services & APIs.
            //String base64Key = "Add Your Key Here";
            return Security.verifyPurchase(/*base64Key*/licenceKey, signedData, signature);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**QUESTION:**  The red error text is on `verifyPurchase` on the line `return Security.verifyPurchase(licenceKey, signedData, signature);`

The **ERROR** hint is `Cannot resolve method verifyPurchase(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)`.

**Why is it doing that?**

Comment: Did you import the class Security in your MainActivity file?

Comment: @Dev_Randalpura I did not think I had to import anything written in the package I am working on. How do I import it if I had to?

Comment: Check the answer, I couldn't add a picture in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

First of all copy this:

[image]

Then add the name of the package in which your `Security` class is in, followed by `Security`. So, this should be your directory for the import:
`name-of-project.name-of-directory.Security;`

If the Security class isn't in a directory, you don't need to use one
Add an import in the beginning of that, so in this case it would be
`import com.example.roughdraft.name-of-directory.Security;`.